# How to use jQuery time interval inside of a jQuery click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a dropdown menu and need the hide the menu bar when the dropdown is expanded and show the menu after a time interval when it is collapsed. The problem is that the code I had is not removing the "toggle-off" class I am adding and removing with jQuery. The result is that the menu bar does not reappear after collapsing the dropdown. The problem is that the part of the jquery function that is within the time interval is not executing.

jQuery:

```
                    $( ".menu-close" ).click(function() {
                        var interval = setInterval(function () {
                            $( ".navbar-header" ).addClass( "toggle-on" );
                            $( ".navbar-header" ).removeClass( "toggle-off" );
                        }, 500);
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        $( "#mob-nav" ).removeClass( "margin-up" );
                        $( "#mob-nav" ).addClass( "margin-down" );
                        $( ".animated" ).removeClass( "go" );
                        $.scrollLock( false );
                    });
```

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is that it does not look nice when collapsing the dropdown while the menu bar has already appeared. As such I want to only show the menu bar again after the dropdown has collapsed. If I remove the var interval = setInterval(function () { ... }, 500); around the $( ".navbar-header" ).addClass( "toggle-on" );  $( ".navbar-header" ).removeClass( "toggle-off" ); the script works but does not look nice.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the CSS, please?

Comment: @doutriforce I don't think this has to do with CSS. I think that it is possible you are not allowed to have the "var interval = setInterval(function () {
                            $( ".navbar-header" ).addClass( "toggle-on" );
                            $( ".navbar-header" ).removeClass( "toggle-off" );
                        }, 500);" within a click function? Because that is the part of the script that is not running, and when I remove the time interval part it works.

Comment: I don't think CSS has anything to do with it, i'm just asking so i can properly simulate what you're doing.

Comment: @doutriforce there is a lot of CSS so it's difficult to replicate it. Better to work with the live site on inspect or something if you can.

Comment: Fair enough. I couldn't find the dropdown there, though. Where is it?

Comment: @doutriforce sorry I forgot to mention this was the mobile/tablet menu only. On that specific page only

Comment: Alright, that's becoming kinda hard to simulate. Lol. Lemme ask you something. Have you tried using `window.setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: @doutriforce I just replaced the setInterval for window.setTimeout in its place but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use setTimout()?

```
$('.menu-open').on('click',function(){
    $('.navbar-header').addClass('toggle-off').removeClass('toggle-on');
    $('.animated').addClass('go');
    $('#mob-nav').addClass('margin-up').removeClass('margin-down');
    $.scrollLock( true );
});
```

and close funciton

```
$('.menu-close').on('click',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.navbar-header').addClass('toggle-on').removeClass('toggle-off');
    }, 500);
    $('#mob-nav').removeClass('margin-up').addClass('margin-down');
    $('.animated').removeClass( "go" );
    $.scrollLock( false );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this function.

```
setInterval(function(){

    if(myDiv.style.display == "block"){
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
    }else{
        myDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

}, 3000);
```

Comment: $( ".menu-close" ).click(function() {
                        var interval = setInterval(function () {
                            $( ".navbar-header" ).addClass( "toggle-on" );
                            $( ".navbar-header" ).removeClass( "toggle-off" );
                        }, 500); } is where the error is I believe. I don't think I can have the time interval inside of the on click function.